# How to strip unicode "punctuation" from Python string

Tags: python, unicode, punctuation

Here's the problem, I have a unicode string as input to a python sqlite query. The query failed ('like'). It turns out the string, 'FRANCE' doesn't have 6 characters, it has seven. And the seventh is . . . unicode U+FEFF, a zero-width no-break space.

How on earth do I trap a class of such things before the query?

Comment: I have to wonder where this string came from.

Comment: That's not punctuation. Its existence indicates a gross failure in some upstream process.

Comment: Seriously, how on earth did you end up with a BOM as the seventh character?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use the unicodedata categories as part of the unicode data table in Python:

```
>>> unicodedata.category(u'a')
'Ll'
>>> unicodedata.category(u'.')
'Po'
>>> unicodedata.category(u',')
'Po'
```

The categories for punctation characters start with 'P' as you can see.
So you need to filter you out char by char (using a list comprehension).

See also:

in your case :

```
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\ufeff')
'Cf'
```

So you may perform some whitelisting based on the categories for characters.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions. They've been most useful!

Comment: Oh, yes, and in answer to the questions in the other remarks the source strings are from webpages (where as you know, anything can happen).

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer. This strikes me as the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

That's also the byte-order mark, BOM. Just cleanup your strings first to eliminate those, using something like:

```
>>> f = u'France\ufeff'
>>> f
u'France\ufeff'
>>> print f
France
>>> f.replace(u'\ufeff', '')
u'France'
>>> f.strip(u'\ufeff')
u'France'
```

Comment: This won't remove arbitrary "crap characters".

Comment: that is true. I was only addressing the one issue described.

Comment: It's only a BOM at the start of a string.

Comment: that's true also, but then I don't know how the data was obtained in the first place; perhaps a concatenation of files made with Notepad on a Windows box.

Answer (score 1):

In general, input validation should be done by using a whitelist of allowable characters if you can define such a thing for your use case.  Then you simply throw out anything that isn't on the whitelist (or reject the input altogether).

If you *can* define a set of allowed characters, then you can use a regular expression to strip out everything else.

For example, lets say you know "country" will only have upper-case English letters and spaces you could strip out everything else, including your nasty unicode letter like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> country = u'FRANCE\ufeff'
>>> clean_pattern = re.compile(u'[^A-Z ]+')
>>> clean_pattern.sub('', country)
u'FRANCE'
```

If you *can't* define a set of allowed characters, you're in deep trouble, because it becomes your task to anticipate all tens of thousands of possible unexpected unicode characters that could be thrown at you--and more and more are added to the specs as languages evolve over the years.

Comment: Oh, and this whitelist method isn't limited to using regular expressions.  If you're okay with something like "any unicode character that's not punctuation" then you could iterate through the string checking the characters against unicodedata.category(...) that pynator suggested.